# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'sortChange' of undefined,This error is showing?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, angular9

Plz guide me,while loading this page,"ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'sortChange' of undefined,"this error is showing,Declared all in module and component,only this error is showing
TS

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { SelectionModel } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { Observable,fromEvent, merge, Subscription, of } from 'rxjs';// RXJS
import { CalendarDataSource } from '../../../../core/e-commerce';
import { environment } from '../../../../../environments/environment';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { LayoutUtilsService, MessageType, QueryParamsModel } from '../../../../core/_base/crud';

// NGRX
import { Store, ActionsSubject } from '@ngrx/store';
import { AppState } from '../../../../core/reducers';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

import { MatPaginator, MatSort, MatDialog,MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material';
import { LayoutConfigService, SubheaderService } from '../../../../core/_base/layout';

import { CalendarModel, CalendarsPageRequested, OneCalendarDeleted, ManyCalendarsDeleted, CalendarsStatusUpdated ,CalendarsReset} from '../../../../core/e-commerce';
import { AuthNoticeService, AuthService, Register, User , UserService } from '../../../../core/auth/';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, RouterLinkWithHref } from '@angular/router';
import { debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, tap, skip, delay, take } from 'rxjs/operators';

let customerdashurl = environment.customerdashboardurl;
let commonUrl = environment.commonUrl;

export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
  description: string;
}
@Component({
  selector: 'kt-eventmanager',
  templateUrl: './eventmanager.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./eventmanager.component.scss']
})
export class EventmanagerComponent implements OnInit {
  dataSource:CalendarDataSource;
  displayedColumns = ['accountId','accountName','companyName','properties','plans','subscribe','emailOut','smsOut','resync','action'];
  expandedElement: PeriodicElement | null;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild('sort1', {static: true}) sort: MatSort;
  // Filter fields
  @ViewChild('searchInput', {static: true}) searchInput: ElementRef;
  filterStatus: string = '';
  filterType: string = '';
  // Selection
  selection = new SelectionModel<CalendarModel>(true, []);
  templatesResult: CalendarModel[] = [];
  private subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];
  superadminId:string;
  shownorecords:boolean=false;
  apicallcnt:number=0;
  sendParams:any={};
  searchcriteria:any={};

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog,
    public snackBar: MatSnackBar,
    private layoutUtilsService: LayoutUtilsService,
    private translate: TranslateService,
    private store: Store<AppState>,
    private router: Router,
    private layoutConfigService: LayoutConfigService,
    private userService: UserService,
    private subheaderService: SubheaderService,
    private toastr:ToastrService,
) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subheaderService.setTitle(this.translate.instant('Subscriptions'));
    this.store.dispatch(new CalendarsReset());
    this.superadminId = localStorage.getItem('superadminId');
    this.layoutConfigService.reloadConfigs();
    // If the user changes the sort order, reset back to the first page.
    const sortSubscription = this.sort.sortChange.subscribe(() => (this.paginator.pageIndex = 0));
    this.subscriptions.push(sortSubscription);

    /* Data load will be triggered in two cases:
    - when a pagination event occurs => this.paginator.page
    - when a sort event occurs => this.sort.sortChange
    **/
    const paginatorSubscriptions = merge(this.sort.sortChange, this.paginator.page).pipe(
      tap(() => this.loadCustomersList())
    )
    .subscribe();
    this.subscriptions.push(paginatorSubscriptions);

    // Filtration, bind to searchInput
    // const searchSubscription = fromEvent(this.searchInput.nativeElement, 'keyup').pipe(
    //   debounceTime(50), // The user can type quite quickly in the input box, and that could trigger a lot of server requests. With this operator, we are limiting the amount of server requests emitted to a maximum of one every 150ms
    //   distinctUntilChanged(), // This operator will eliminate duplicate values
    //   tap(() => {
    //     this.paginator.pageIndex = 0;
    //     this.loadCustomersList();
    //   })
    // )
    // .subscribe();
    // this.subscriptions.push(searchSubscription);
    // Init DataSource
    this.dataSource = new CalendarDataSource(this.store);

    console.log(this.dataSource);
    const entitiesSubscription = this.dataSource.entitySubject.pipe(
      skip(1),
      distinctUntilChanged()
    ).subscribe(res => {
      this.templatesResult = res;
      this.apicallcnt++;
      if(this.templatesResult.length == 0 && this.apicallcnt>2)
      {this.shownorecords = true;}else{this.shownorecords=false;}
    });
    this.subscriptions.push(entitiesSubscription);
    // First load
    of(undefined).pipe(take(1), delay(1000)).subscribe(() => { // Remove this line, just loading imitation
      this.loadCustomersList();
    }); // Remove this line, just loading imitation
  }
  loadCustomersList() {
    this.selection.clear();

    const queryParams = new QueryParamsModel(
      this.filterConfiguration(),
      this.sort.direction,
      this.sort.active,
      this.paginator.pageIndex,
      this.paginator.pageSize
    );
    // Call request from server
    this.store.dispatch(new CalendarsPageRequested({ page: queryParams }));
    this.selection.clear();
  }

  filterConfiguration(): any {
    const filter: any = {};
    const searchText: string = this.searchInput.nativeElement.value;
  
    if (this.filterStatus && this.filterStatus.length > 0) {
      filter.status = +this.filterStatus;
    }
  
    if (this.filterType && this.filterType.length > 0) {
      filter.type = +this.filterType;
    }
  
    filter.accountName = searchText;
    if (!searchText) {
      return filter;
    }
  
    filter.email = searchText;
  
    filter.companyName = searchText;
    // filter.userName = searchText;
  
    // filter.id = searchText;
    return filter;
    }
  
}
```

Plz guide me,while loading this page,"ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'sortChange' of undefined,"this error is showing,Declared all in module and component,only this error is showing TS

Answer (score 1):

Consider this line `@ViewChild('sort1', {static: true}) sort: MatSort;`

This is where you have declared the property `sort`

In the angular life cycle hooks, when you call `ngOnInit()`, the view has not yet initialized. You need to call sort after the view initializes i.e in the `AfterViewInit` life cycle hook.

Simply remove content

```typescript
   // If the user changes the sort order, reset back to the first page.
    const sortSubscription = this.sort.sortChange.subscribe(() => (this.paginator.pageIndex = 0));
    this.subscriptions.push(sortSubscription);

    /* Data load will be triggered in two cases:
    - when a pagination event occurs => this.paginator.page
    - when a sort event occurs => this.sort.sortChange
    **/
    const paginatorSubscriptions = merge(this.sort.sortChange, this.paginator.page).pipe(
      tap(() => this.loadCustomersList())
    )
    .subscribe();
    this.subscriptions.push(paginatorSubscriptions);
```

and move it to `ngAfterViewInit()` function

```typescript
  export class EventmanagerComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  
  ...

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // If the user changes the sort order, reset back to the first page.
    const sortSubscription = this.sort.sortChange.subscribe(() => (this.paginator.pageIndex = 0));
    this.subscriptions.push(sortSubscription);

    /* Data load will be triggered in two cases:
    - when a pagination event occurs => this.paginator.page
    - when a sort event occurs => this.sort.sortChange
    **/
    const paginatorSubscriptions = merge(this.sort.sortChange, this.paginator.page).pipe(
      tap(() => this.loadCustomersList())
    )
    .subscribe();
    this.subscriptions.push(paginatorSubscriptions);
  }
```